# using PAPI for reading Performance monitoring counters in Intel Core i7

Tags: multicore, performance, papi

I want to read performance monitoring couters in Core i7
The out put for each event just contains 1 data and has no information about the core this data is for.
How can I read the events counts for each core separately by PAPI?

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

PAPI counts are based on threads and not on cores. If you want core-based measurements,  you may want to consider using intel pcm - which is capable of providing per-core counts.

The PCM is bit tricky to use and the counts may not match with PAPI - since PCM counts or accounts things slightly differently.

Does it answer your question?

tjr

Comment: Hi @TJR, do you know if PCM can be run within Linux kernel or Xen hypervisor kernel? Especially in Xen hypervisor, only the xen kernel space has the Privilege level 0, which is needed by the PCM to access those registers.